# Is it possible to determine web browser's termination event?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am building a chat room and I have to determine whether a user is online or not. So when a user logs in, I update his status as online and when he logs out, I update his status as offline, but when the user simply closes the browser, the status remains online.

To fix this I need to execute a server side code on the event of browser termination. How do I do this?

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload) is what you are looking for.

When a user closes a browser window, the `unload` event is triggered. You could trigger an ajax request on this event that posts to the server that the user has closed his/her window.

```
window.onunload = function(){
    // make an ajax request that notifies the 
    // server that user has closed the window
}
```

Comment: Would this always hit the server even if a connection can't be made fast enough?

Comment: He may need to make the request not asynchronous, eg. adding `async:false` to the jQuery ajax request options...